# Sort list of lists by length of member lists

Tags: r

I have output from a package (apcluster) that comes as a S4 object type. One of the members is a list of lists determining the members of each cluster found. I want to sort that list by the length (largest clusters).

My code right now looks like

```
ap.result <- apcluster(args)
clusters <- ap.result@cluster #list of lists
```

I can then access individual members of `clusters` by `clusters[[i]]` but the order is semi-random. If I `unlist(clusters)` then I get a vector without knowing which sub-list it came from.

How can I sort `ap.result@cluster` to be ordered by longest member list to shortest member list?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `clusters[rank(sapply(clusters, length))]`?

Comment: @SeñorO I think you mean `order`, not `rank`. (I think rank will not work if you have sub-lists of the same length.)

Comment: Those combined worked, thanks! `clusters[order(sapply(clusters,length),decreasing=T)]`

Comment: @IanFiddes Go ahead and write an answer yourself, then, so you can accept it!

Comment: I have not thought of that before, but I think this might be useful functionality. I am considering implementing a sort() function for APResult/ExClust objects in one of the next releases of the apcluster package. (I am the maintainer of the package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments, here is the solution:

```
clusters[order(sapply(clusters,length),decreasing=T)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Version 1.3.4 of the package has been released on CRAN today (the Windows and Mac OS X binaries may take 1-2 more days to be online). Inspired by Ian's request, the new version includes a sort() method for rearranging the cluster according to a given sorting criterion. The solution to Ian's question would now be the following:

```
sort(ap.result, decreasing=TRUE, sortBy="size")
```