# sort list according to length of list element R

Tags: r

I am trying to sort my list element.But i get the following error.

```
Error in order(rmnull) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
```

The code which cause the error is:

```
order(rmnull)
```

where,
    `rmnull`

is my list. I have 100 lists, here i posted the one of them.

```
rmnull:
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "VEGFA"  "EPHB2"  "GRIN2B" "AP2M1"  "KCNJ11" "ABCC8" 

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "VEGFA" "VTN"   "PRKCA" "ADCY5"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "VEGFA" "KDR"   "GRB2"  "ADRB1"

[[1]][[4]]
[1] "VEGFA" "AKT1"  "AKT2" 

[[1]][[5]]
[1] "VEGFA" "CTGF"  "AP3D1" "AP3S2"

[[1]][[6]]
[1] "VEGFA" "YBX1"  "SMAD3" "ATF3" 

[[1]][[7]]
[1] "VEGFA"  "AKT1"   "IRS1"   "ATP2A2"
```

and my desired output is as follows:

```
[[1]][[4]]
[1] "VEGFA" "AKT1"  "AKT2" 

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "VEGFA" "VTN"   "PRKCA" "ADCY5"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "VEGFA" "KDR"   "GRB2"  "ADRB1"

[[1]][[5]]
[1] "VEGFA" "CTGF"  "AP3D1" "AP3S2"

[[1]][[6]]
[1] "VEGFA" "YBX1"  "SMAD3" "ATF3" 

[[1]][[7]]
[1] "VEGFA"  "AKT1"   "IRS1"   "ATP2A2"

[[1]][[1]]
[1] "VEGFA"  "EPHB2"  "GRIN2B" "AP2M1"  "KCNJ11" "ABCC8"
```

The output of `dput` is as follows:

```
list(list(c("VEGFA", "EPHB2", "GRIN2B", "AP2M1", "KCNJ11", "ABCC8"
), c("VEGFA", "VTN", "PRKCA", "ADCY5"), c("VEGFA", "KDR", "GRB2", 
"ADRB1"), c("VEGFA", "AKT1", "AKT2"), c("VEGFA", "CTGF", "AP3D1", 
"AP3S2"), c("VEGFA", "YBX1", "SMAD3", "ATF3"), c("VEGFA", "AKT1", 
"IRS1", "ATP2A2")), list(c("HHEX", "EFEMP2", "TP53", "ARIH2", 
"ENSA", "ABCC8"), c("HHEX", "TLE1", "POLB", "PRKCA", "ADCY5"), 
c("HHEX", "TLE1", "ATN1", "MAGI2", "ADRB1"), c("HHEX", "JUN", 
"ESR1", "AKT2"), c("HHEX", "TLE1", "CDK1", "BUB1", "AP3B1", 
"AP3S2"), c("HHEX", "JUN", "ATF3"), c("HHEX", "PML", "BCL2", 
"ATP2A2")), list(c("PPP1R3A", "RPS6KA1", "MAPK1", "TP53", 
"ARIH2", "ENSA", "ABCC8"), c("PPP1R3A", "PLN", "PRKACA", "ADCY5"
 ), c("PPP1R3A", "RPS6KA1", "GRB2", "ADRB1"), c("PPP1R3A", "RPS6KA1", 
"PDPK1", "AKT2"), c("PPP1R3A", "RPS6KA1", "MAPK1", "IRS1", "AP3S1", 
"AP3S2"), c("PPP1R3A", "RPS6KA1", "MAPK1", "SMAD3", "ATF3"), 
c("PPP1R3A", "PLN", "ATP2A2")), list(c("TCF7L2", "EP300", 
"TP53", "ARIH2", "ENSA", "ABCC8"), c("TCF7L2", "PSEN1", "PRKACA", 
"ADCY5"), c("TCF7L2", "CTNNB1", "MAGI2", "ADRB1"), c("TCF7L2", 
"EP300", "ESR1", "AKT2"), c("TCF7L2", "CSNK2A1", "ARR3", "AP3B1", 
"AP3S2"), c("TCF7L2", "EP300", "SMAD3", "ATF3"), c("TCF7L2", 
"CSNK2A1", "IRS1", "ATP2A2")), list(c("KCNQ1", "TRAF6", "SIGIRR", 
"ENO2", "ENSA", "ABCC8"), c("KCNQ1", "KCNE4", "PRKCA", "ADCY5"
), c("KCNQ1", "AKAP9", "GRIN1", "DLG4", "ADRB1"), c("KCNQ1", 
"TRAF6", "XIAP", "AKT2"), c("KCNQ1", "AKAP9", "GRIN1", "CLTC", 
"AP3B1", "AP3S2"), c("KCNQ1", "AKAP9", "PPP1CA", "TP53", "ATF3"
), c("KCNQ1", "AKAP9", "PPP1CA", "BCL2", "ATP2A2")), list(c("LIPC", 
"LRP1", "DLG4", "KCNJ2", "KCNJ8", "ABCC8"), c("LIPC", "LRP1", 
"PRKACA", "ADCY5"), c("LIPC", "LRP1", "DLG4", "ADRB1"), c("LIPC", 
"APOB", "HSP90AA1", "AKT2"), c("LIPC", "LRP1", "CTGF", "AP3D1", 
"AP3S2"), c("LIPC", "LRP1", "PRKACA", "NFKB1", "ATF3"), c("LIPC", 
"LRP1", "SHC1", "IRS2", "ATP2A2")), list(c("PRKCB", "DAB2", "AP2M1", 
"KCNJ11", "ABCC8"), c("PRKCB", "RGS2", "ADCY5"), c("PRKCB", "PTPN11", 
"GRB2", "ADRB1"), c("PRKCB", "GSK3B", "AKT2"), c("PRKCB", "OCLN", 
"CSNK1A1", "AP3B1", "AP3S2"), c("PRKCB", "BTK", "TP53", "ATF3"
 ), c("PRKCB", "PTPN11", "IRS2", "ATP2A2")), list(c("OGG1", "PRKCA", 
"DLG4", "KCNJ2", "KCNJ8", "ABCC8"), c("OGG1", "PRKCA", "ADCY5"
), c("OGG1", "PRKCA", "DLG4", "ADRB1"), c("OGG1", "PRKCA", "HSP90AA1", 
"AKT2"), c("OGG1", "PRKCA", "PICK1", "ARF1", "AP3D1", "AP3S2"
), c("OGG1", "PRKCA", "TP53", "ATF3"), c("OGG1", "PRKCA", "BCL2", 
"ATP2A2")))
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's better to provide a `dput` of your list. In general, something like `rmnull[order(lengths(rmnull))]` usually works

Comment: From your output It seems a list of lists of vectors... as suggested you should post the output of `dput(rmnull)`...

Comment: Not sure if [this is a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209188/sort-list-of-lists-by-length-of-member-lists)...

Comment: Looks like @Sotos is right, you could try this: `sort(ap.result, decreasing=TRUE, sortBy="size")`

Comment: Hello thanks all, as digEmAll suggested I posted the output of dput.

Comment: Hello Bas, here it does not work and gave an error.  "Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  unused argument (sortBy = "size")" which was i suffered when i simply used the sort only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lapply(
    SomeList,
    function(SmallList) {
        SmallList[
           order(
              sapply(
                 SmallList,
                 length
              )
           )
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks TheComeOnMan. It's working. Really nice way to do it. Thanks again.